# Graph API - how meaww and nametests get my friends list without taggable_friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I've recently applied for taggable_friends permission and it was denied. I understand that this permission is only for tagging user's friends and if I want to get the user's friends who also use my app, I have to use user_friends.

But I am confused here because, I've recently discovered that a lot of personality test websites can get my friends who doesn't even use ( or used in the past) those apps (i.e meaww.com/activities/question/batman_twin_yours/2355). And the core intention of these personality testing websites are not tagging, just sharing the result in the user's timeline.

I believe the apps of the above mentioned websites, do not have the taggable_friends permission (since they do not ask users to tag anyone) or is of version 1.0.

Is it at all possible that anyone can suggest me how I can get a user's friends' profile pictures and names like those websites?

Comment: You can’t, and you are not supposed to. Period. What other apps do, doesn’t matter. You are not allowed to rob banks either, just because other people might be doing it.

Comment: @abdullah-al-sayeed how you made nametests like websites. how to write those images. are you using imagemagic or what

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe says: You can't.

I am currently building 'funny' ('bullshit' or 'humoristic' are maybe better terms to describe them) - tests/quizzes and I am trying a workaround:

get a list of the users' (endpoint: /me) -profilepictures. (Requires 'user_photos' permission)

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/photos?type=uploaded&fields=id,picture.width(800).height(800),link', $accessToken);
```

Than scan for likes on those pictures.

```
$response = $fb->get('/'. $tmpId .'/likes', $accessToken);
```

In the likes are id's and names of users. 
It's not a complete friends_list - but if you are like me, OK with just 'some' friends to display something 'useful'...

(With the user_id you get the public profile pic)

Hope I could help!

Comment: how to make nametests like websites. how to write those images. are you using imagemagic or what